# Sorting using MonthName and Year

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table structure like this:-

```
       ID       Month              Year

       1      January               2015
       2      February              2015
       3      March                 2014
       4      April                 2014
       5      May                   2014
       6      June                  2014
       7      July                  2014
       8      August                2014
       9      September             2014
      10      October               2014
      11      November              2014
      12      December              2014
```

> I want to sort this using old year's month , year first if not came in
>   month in current year  otherwise want to sort using current year's
>   month, current year (if months exist in current year) .

Expected output is:-

```
            Month              Year

           March                 2014
           April                 2014
           May                   2014
           June                  2014
           July                  2014
           August                2014
           September             2014
           October               2014
           November              2014
           December              2014
           January               2015
           February              2015
```

Comment: Please provide your code..What have you tried??

Comment: My query is :-       SELECT Months,IF(flag=1,new_year,old_year) as Year
FROM (SELECT MONTH(now())>=ID as flag,year(now()) as new_year ,year(now())-1 as old_year,Months                                     (where i have two column in months_stats Id, monthname)
FROM
MONTHS_STATS) AS T;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in order to get a value which can be ordered according to your needs. Something like

```
SELECT M.*, 
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(M.Month,' ',M.Year),'%M %Y') AS 'myorder'
  FROM yourtable M
ORDER BY myorder ASC;
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

try this function in query may help in your case

```
Select STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(Month,'',Year),'%M %Y') AS 'myorder' from tableName Order By Cutom ASC
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT MONTH,YEAR FROM TABLE_NAME ORDER BY YEAR DESC,MONTH ASC

Think this should do the trick